# AJAX dropbutton link

Tags: views, 8, theming, forms

I have a dropbutton in an admin view. It's currently got links built using URL::fromRoute

I want one of these links/buttons to work asynchronously.

This is what I currently have:

```
$dropdownButtons = [
    '#type' => 'dropbutton',
    '#links' => [
      'a' => [
        'title' => $send_verification_link_text,
        'url' => $send_verification_email_url,
      ],
      'b' => [
        'title' => $this->t('Remove person'),
        'url' => $remove_person_url,
      ],
    ],
  ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume these are links to Ajax enabled route yes ?? i hope so lol any way heres is how ... see this example from a list builder:

```
$parent['operations']['data']['#links']['clone'] = [
  'title' => $this->t('AJAX!!!'),
  'weight' => 2,
  'url' => Url::fromRoute('someroute_name', ['id' => $entity->id]),
  'attributes'=> [
    'class' => 'use-ajax'
  ]
];
```

all you need to do is add 
'attributes'=> ['class' => 'use-ajax']
more info see my old comment ... https://api.drupal.org/comment/62725#comment-62725

Comment: This is working for me now. Thought I'd tried doing it that way but must have got some part of it wrong...thanks.